# Biblatex bibliography - how to output DOI/URL differently based on digital copy/to-be printed copy

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, hyperref, urls, doi

What is the best practice using biblatex and hyperref packages to tweak the bibliography so that when the URL/DOI/ISBN "IDs" are present, they are shown as links with the placeholder "URL/DOI/ISBN" respectively, for instance? Is there some already available properties?

I would also like to switch to hard-copy to-be-printed too, so that this feature is turned off and the above information is printed fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of fields in `biblatex` is controlled via field formats.

The standard format for `doi` is ([ll. 495-499 in `biblatex.def` (v3.16)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L495))

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

that for URL ([l. 582 in `biblatex.def` (v3.16)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L582))

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
```

you can easily change these formats so that they only print a "DOI" or "URL" and link that with `\href{<link target>}{<text>}` (note that you then need to load `hyperref`).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \href{https://doi.org/#1}{\mkbibacro{DOI}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{%
  \href{#1}{\mkbibacro{URL}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,ctan}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: CTAN (2006). CTAN. The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network. url (visited on 01/10/2006). Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi.]