# Link but don't print a hyperref link in references, but using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

My question is exactly the same as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630095/link-but-dont-print-a-hyperref-link-in-references):

> Generally, URLs are not pretty nor compact. How can I embed a
> hyperlink to the documents URL without printing the URL in the
> reference catalog?

The solution given there is valid for BiBTeX. Is there a similar solution for biblatex?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{knuth1984,
  title={Literate Programming},
  author={Donald E. Knuth},
  journal={The Computer Journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={97--111},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Oxford University Press},
  url={https://doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/27.2.97}
}
\end{filecontents}
 
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
 
\begin{document}
 
\section*{Current output:}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
 
\section*{Desired output:}
\begin{description}[labelwidth=0.5cm, itemindent=0cm, leftmargin=!, font=\normalfont]
  \item[{[1]}] 
    Donald E. Knuth,
    ``\href{https://doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/27.2.97}{Literate Programming}''
    In: \emph{The Computer Journal} 27.2 (1984), pp. 97-111.
\end{description}
 
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

EDITED:

As comments suggest, the solutions given to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48400/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-dois-url-or-isbn), or its parent [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available), give me one solution:

```
\newbibmacro{string+url}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{url}{#1}{%
    \href{\thefield{url}}{#1}%
  }%                
}                   
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+url}{#1}}               
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{url}{}
```

The small problem is that if you want to respect the original formatting of the bibliography style used, you have to replicate it. With the above code, I have lost the quotation marks in the title. If I want to recover quotations marks:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+url}{\mkbibquote{#1}}}
```

This should be done for every entrytype, and, if you want to change the bibliography style, modify accordingly. Maybe not a big deal.

Alternatively, I have found the `DeclareFieldInputHandler` command. This command *define a data input handler for  when it is
read from the .bbl.* according to the biblatex manual. Therefore you can use the following code:

```
\DeclareFieldInputHandler{title}{\def\Newvalue{\usebibmacro{string+url}{#1}}}               
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{url}{}
```

[image]

I am unaware of the possible side effects of this input handler redefinition.

Comment: certainly. But you should add a proper, small complete example that can be used to test solutions and describe what you want instead of simply linking to another question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer:Ok. MWE added. Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48409/36296

Comment: Or duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48506/14500

Comment: @cabohah Almost. The only problem is that you have to completely redefine the format of the "title" field for each type of entry. If you want to change the style of the bibliography, then you have to modify the "DeclareFieldFormat" lines accordingly.