Add fontawesome icon at end of each bibliographic entry
I'm trying to reduce the size of a bibliography by simply changing the URL (which in some cases is way too long) by an icon. I managed to add icon after the year entry (so that it appears last in the entry), and it looks like this:

I have two questions:

Is it possible to remove the dot at the end of the entry? I searched online but I can't find a way to do this.
Is there a better entry I can use, instead of adding the icon after the year?

This is the MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{AragonDuarte:2016,
    author = {Arag{\'o}n, Alejandro M. and Duarte, C. Armando},
    date-added = {2023-11-20 16:12:53 +0100},
    date-modified = {2024-11-14 11:57:52 +0100},
    edition = {1st.~Edition},
    isbn = {9780323855167},
    keywords = {books},
    month = {November 9},
    publisher = {Elsevier},
    title = {Fundamentals of Enriched Finite Element Methods},
    year = {2023 \href{https://shop.elsevier.com/books/fundamentals-of-enriched-finite-element-methods/aragon/978-0-323-85515-0}{\faExternalLink}}}
\end{filecontents}


% bibliography
\usepackage[natbib, backend=biber, sorting=ydnt, doi=false, eprint=false, maxnames=99, giveninits=true, style=numeric-comp, isbn=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{keyreferences}
\defbibenvironment{keyrefs}
  {\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1.5em, topsep=0pt,itemsep=-0.5ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex, ] }
  {\end{enumerate}}
  {\item}


\usepackage[backend=biber,]{biblatex}

\begin{document}


\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[env=keyrefs,keyword={books},title={\normalsize Books}]

%\printbibliography
\end{document}


Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

There are some bibliography styles that make the title into a link. For BibLaTeX see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available?noredirect=1&lq=1. For BibTeX you can use urlbst, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630095/link-but-dont-print-a-hyperref-link-in-references/630130.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added a MWE.

@Marijn I actually like the icon at the end.

If you want to get rid of the full stop at the end for entries with the URL symbol you can replace the punctuation with the symbol (and take the URL from the url field). This means we just need to redefine \finentrypunct.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
  natbib,
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric-comp, 
  sorting=ydnt,
  maxnames=99, giveninits=true,
  doi=false, eprint=false, isbn=false, url=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{keyreferences}
\defbibenvironment{keyrefs}
  {\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1.5em, topsep=0pt,itemsep=-0.5ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex, ] }
  {\end{enumerate}}
  {\item}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifbibliography}
   and not test {\iffieldundef{url}}}
    {\addspace\href{\thefield{url}}{\faExternalLink}}
    {\addperiod}}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@book{AragonDuarte:2016,
  author    = {Aragón, Alejandro M. and Duarte, C. Armando},
  edition   = {1},
  isbn      = {9780323855167},
  keywords  = {books},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
  title     = {Fundamentals of Enriched Finite Element Methods},
  year      = {2023},
  url       = {https://shop.elsevier.com/books/fundamentals-of-enriched-finite-element-methods/aragon/978-0-323-85515-00},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[env=keyrefs,keyword={books},title={\normalsize Books}]
\end{document}


