# BibLaTeX: create an hyperlink to doi in the reference items

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to hide the full DOI url by linking it to a string. I report an example taken from a paper about what I want to achieve. [image: example]

As you can see, there are "CrossRef" and "PubMed" that are links to DOI or URL of the article.

I've also tried what is suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23832/biblatex-make-title-hyperlink-to-doi-url-if-available), but with this method, you can only refer to a specific field in the reference's records.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please show a Minimal Working Example, so that people can test your code and suggest modifications based on what packages you're using.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you want. Do you want all your DOIs to just show the clickable link "CrossRef", or do you want different texts depending on additional factors? (If you want all DOI links to show the same text, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/624758/35864)

Comment: Any news here? As mentioned above, it does not appear to be very clear to several people what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Additionally, a good answer will depend on the code you are currently using, so you should also share your current bibliography/citation setup with us. Ideally in a short example document.

Comment: I try the solution suggested by @moewe (see the [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624758/biblatex-bibliography-how-to-output-doi-url-differently-based-on-digital-copy)). It works for me.